# un find con una respuesta de otro find

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola estoy comenzando y tengo un código en donde quisiera una ayuda, (solo puedo trabajar con promesas por versiones del servidor), quisiera una búsqueda y con el resultado de esta hacer otra búsqueda, acá el código:

```
  var hoy = moment().startOf('day').toISOString();
    var promocionesList = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Promociones.find({
            "fechaFin": {
                "$lt": hoy
            }
        }, function (err, promociones) {
            if (promociones) {
                resolve(promociones);
            } else {
                reject('ocurrio un problema intentalo nuevamente')
            }
        })
    });


    var userPromoList = function (listaUsuario) {
       
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            User.find({ id: listaUsuario._user, propiedades: { promociones: true } }
                , function (err, usuarios) {
                    if (usuarios) {
                        resolve(usuarios);
                    } else {
                        reject('ocurrio un problema intentalo nuevamente')
                    }
                })
        });
    }

    promocionesList.then(function (salida) {
        userPromoList(salida).then(function (segunda) {
           console.log('salida', segunda)
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("err   ..  ", err)

        })
```

Disculpen no se como hacer, lo siento apenas comienzo, gracias....se que debo iterar pero honestamente no se...de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tenés que concatenar las promesas, los métodos de mongoose y mongodb devuelven promesas, no hace falta pasar el callback...

si en la función que pasas a `.then` devolves una promesa podes concatenarlas de la siguiente manera

```javascript
Promociones.find(...)
  .then(result => {
     return OtherModel.find(...) 
  })
  .then(result2 => {
    return unaFuncionQueDevuelveUnaPromesa(resilt2)
  })
  .then(result3 => {
    // ...y asi sigue 
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // cualquier error que se genere en la cadena lo captamos acá...
  })
```